# Rails 'remote:true' ignored when params provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails (5.2.4.2) app

I am using button_to + remote: true, and this is working as expected -> ajax call fired, all is OK.

But then I add 'params' to the button_to. Params are added to the form as hidden input (as expected) but when I click on the button, the request made is not remote, and all the page content is updated.

Problematic: button_to + remote + params -> this code seems to ignore the `remote:true`, although I see `data-remote="true"` in the form tag

```
<%= button_to ent_path(ent),
      {remote: true,
      method: :patch,
      class:"btn btn-primary",
      params: {ent: {active_a: false}}
    } do
%>
  <span>TEEEST</span>
<% end %>
```

Working as expected:

```
<%= button_to ent_path(ent),
      {remote: true,
      method: :patch,
      class:"btn btn-primary",
    } do
%>
  <span>TEEEST</span>
<% end %>
```

So my purpose is to have the button_to remote and update the `ent` record, changing the `active_a` attribute depending on some logic

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass any extra parameters via the link path, like this

```rb
<%= button_to ent_path(ent, active_a: false),
      {remote: true,
      method: :patch,
      class:"btn btn-primary",
    } do
%>
  <span>TEEEST</span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the `remote:true` was working properly. But there was a `redirect_back` in the controller that was executed in case of some custom logic, so that appeared as if the button is working without `remote:true`